# Substituting EE4 layout tag append, with Stash

Tags: stash, layouts

DRY: Template Layouts is nice because of the single layout tag.

```
{layout:set:append name='url'}{path='page1'}{/layout:set:append}
{layout:set:append name='url'}{path='page1/page2'}{/layout:set:append}

{layout:set:append name="title"}test1{/layout:set:append}
{layout:set:append name="title"}test2{/layout:set:append}

<ul>
    {layout:url}
    <li><a href="{value}">{layout:title index='{index}'}</a></li>
    {/layout:url}
</ul>
```

The result will be:

```
<ul >
  <li><a href="http://mysite/page1">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mysite/page1/page2">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

It is possible to obtain the same result using Stash (if I'm not using yet EE4) ?